# Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection LoadProject method throws Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using .netCore, the below code (ProjectCollection LoadProject(csprojectFilePath) throws InvalidProjectFile exception.

The same code working fine in .netFramework but throws an exception in .net Core. Am I missing something?

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection pjtCollection = new 
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection();
var project = pjtCollection.LoadProject(csprojectFilePath);
project.SetProperty("TargetFrameworkVersion", "v4.6");
project.Save(csprojectFilePath);
```

**ExpectedResults:**
Load the project file and update the target framework version and save the file.

**Actual Results:**
Here     pjtCollection.LoadProject(csprojectFilePath) throws InvalidprojectFileException

**Message:**
The imported project "C:\Users\~\source\repos\BuildSolution\BuildSolution\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  E:...............csproj

**Help Keyword from exception:** MSBuild.ImportedProjectNotFound

**stack trace:**
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args) in /*/src/Shared/ProjectErrorUtilities.cs:line 412
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpression(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, String unescapedExpression, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError, List`1& imports) in /*/src/Build/Evaluation/Evaluator.cs:line 2413
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) in /*/src/Build/Evaluation/Evaluator.cs:line 2168
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult) in /_/src/Build/Evaluation/Evaluator.cs:line 1934
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement) in /*/src/Build/Evaluation/Evaluator.cs:line 1812
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) in /_/src/Build/Evaluation/Evaluator.cs:line 985
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext) in /*/src/Build/Evaluation/Evaluator.cs:line 716
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext) in /*/src/Build/Definition/Project.cs:line 2727
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext) in /*/src/Build/Definition/Project.cs:line 2687
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext) in /_/src/Build/Definition/Project.cs:line 2798
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext) in /*/src/Build/Definition/Project.cs:line 515
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion) in /_/src/Build/Definition/ProjectCollection.cs:line 1080
   at BuildSolution.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\~\source\repos\BuildSolution\BuildSolution\Program.cs:line 31

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Microsoft.Build` NuGet Package in .NET Core and then

```
var projectRootElement = ProjectRootElement.Open(csprojPath);
projectRootElement.AddProperty("TargetFrameworkVersion", "v4.6");
projectRootElement.Save();
```

Tested in .NetCore 5.0 and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, according to the [Applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to) section of the `ProjectCollection` class's documentation page, it's not supported by any version of .Net Core.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank You. Is there any alternative dll/nuget package can be used in .net core to load and edit the .csproj file. I tried using Buildalyzer but there project properties cannot be edited (as it has only get accessor).

Comment: Non comes to mind, on the other hand, a `csproj` is essentially an XML file that can be edited like any other XML file.